# (Firebase) Assign value to global variable from a returned completion handler function

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function that retrieves the "users" node of my Firebase database, and I am trying to assign a global variable equal to the number of users that are in this "users" node like so:

```
func getUsers(completionHandler:@escaping (Int) -> ()) {

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users")

    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

            let user = User()

            user.id = snapshot.key
            user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)                
            self.users.append(user)
            completionHandler(self.users.count)
        }

    }, withCancel: nil)

}
```

Then, in the viewDidLoad() function, I try to assign a global variable equal to the number of users in the "users" node like this:

```
var userCount: Int?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getUsers(){ (count) in
        self.userCount = count
    }

    print(userCount)
}
```

This prints nil, and it should be 12, which is the amount of users I added to my Firebase database. Since I am somewhat unfamiliar with completion handlers, I am unsure how to fix this.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your completion closure is `@escaping` that is async for that reason `print(userCount)` get executed before the completion block returns and you are getting `nil`.
Try This:

```
var userCount: Int?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getUsers(){ (count) in
        self.userCount = count
        print(self.userCount)
    }
}
```

Or you can remove `@escaping` and make your completion closure sync.

```
func getUsers(completionHandler:(Int) -> ()) {

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users")

    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

            let user = User()

            user.id = snapshot.key
            user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)                
            self.users.append(user)
            completionHandler(self.users.count)
        }

    }, withCancel: nil)

}
```

Comment: Removing `@escaping` brings up the following error: `Closure use of non-escaping parameter "completionHandler" may allow it to escape` on the following line: `completionHandler(self.users.count)`

Comment: If you don't want to block your main Thread than you should use asynchronous. If you use synchronous then your next line of code will execute after the closure return.

Comment: You will get a clear concept from here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I cannot figure out from that website link how to fix my error. I don't want it to escape (I think, because that would make it synchronous, which I want) and yet it is forcing me to add `@escaping` or it won't build

Comment: Probably its showing error because `completionHandler(self.users.count)` is  inside another async completion closure but your function is sync.

Comment: Is it possible to make the inner completion closure synchronous? I thought they were synchronous by default

Comment: My suggestion is to use async. Because you have called the `getUsers ` method in `viewDidLoad()`. Calling a sync function in `viewDidLoad()` will slow down loading your view controller or you could get slow push animation while navigate.